# Prove that if $\mathrm{e}^X$ and $\mathrm{e}^Y$ are uncorrelated, then so are $X$ and $Y$ when $(X,Y)$ are jointly normal.

Tags: probability-theory, correlation

Well, the title says it all. I need to prove that if $(X,Y)$ are jointly normal and $\mathrm{e}^X$ and $\mathrm{e}^Y$ are uncorrelated, then so are $X$ and $Y$.

Although the book (A Probability Path, by Resnick) does not make it explicit, I'm assuming that "jointly normal" means a bivariate normal distribution (as follows from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Joint_normality) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function), subsection "Bivariate case").

I really don't know how to start solving this. Any help or hint will be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: "Well, the title says it all."  You would do better by your Readers to include the problem statement in the body of the Question.  There is no benefit to those who want to help you by the extra burden imposed in trying to unpack a cryptic problem statement from the title and "correlate" this with the remarks added in the body.

Comment: Consider that P(e^x < a, e^y < b) = P(x < ln(a), y < ln(b)).

Comment: @hardmath The title is actually the complete problem statement, and I just copied it into the body of the post. I think your harsh comment was uncalled for.

Comment: @NarekMargaryan thanks for your suggestion, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Hint: $\mathsf{E}[e^{X+Y}]=\exp[\mu_X+\mu_Y+\frac12(\sigma^2_X+2\rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y+\sigma^2_y)]$

Comment: @JGWang thank you very much, your hint helped a lot, and I could solve the problem.

Comment: @NarekMargaryan At best useless, at worst misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hint given by @JGWang I could solve this. I provide my answer here:

Let $(X,Y) \sim \mathcal{N}((\mu_X, \mu_Y), \Sigma)$, with
$$\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_X^2 & \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) \\\mathrm{Cov}(Y,X) & \sigma_Y^2 \end{pmatrix}.$$

By completing the square, we can prove that
$$\mathbf{E}(\mathrm{e}^X) = \exp\left(\frac{(\mu_X + \sigma_X^2)^2 - \mu_X^2}{2\sigma_X^2}\right),$$
idem with $Y$. Now, if we denote $\rho = \frac{\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma_Y\sigma_Y}$, then it is known that the density function of $(X,Y)$ is
\begin{align}
f_{X,Y}(x,y) =& \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_X\sigma_Y\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \times \dotsb\\ & \dotsb \times\exp \left(-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[ \frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2} + \frac{(y-\mu_Y)^2}{\sigma_Y^2} - \frac{2\rho(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}\right]\right).
\end{align}
With this, we can replicate the computations made before (i.e. by completing the square) and prove that
$$\mathbf{E}(\mathrm{e}^{X+Y}) = \exp\left(\mu_X + \mu_Y + \frac{1}{2}\left( \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2 + 2\rho \sigma_X\sigma_Y \right)\right).$$
Given that $\mathrm{e}^X$ and $\mathrm{e}^Y$ are uncorrelated, then we have that $\mathbf{E}(\mathrm{e}^{X+Y})=\mathbf{E}(\mathrm{e}^{X})\mathbf{E}(\mathrm{e}^{Y})$. Matching terms, we get
$$\rho \sigma_X \sigma_Y = 0 \implies \rho = 0 \implies \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = 0,$$
where both implications are true because $\sigma_X,\sigma_Y > 0$.